# delete pairs $(x,y)$ of a list with $x \le x_{0}$

Tags: list-manipulation

How we can remove all pairs `{x,y}` of a list which begin from a special `x`.

For example:

```
list={{1,2},{4,5},{5,9},{8,13},{9,0.1},{15,-0.2},{17,-9},{23,2}};
```

We want keep pairs in which `x=<9`:

`extractlist={{1,2},{4,5},{5,9},{8,13},{9,0.1}};`

Comment: If the x's are ordered (as coolwater points out), then `TakeWhile[list, #[[1]] <= 9 &]` may be (yet another) option worth considering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
list = {{1, 2}, {4, 5}, {5, 9}, {8, 13}, {9, 0.1}, {15, -0.2}, {17, -9}, {23, 
    2}};

trimmedList = Select[list, #[[1]] <= 9 &]

(* {{1, 2}, {4, 5}, {5, 9}, {8, 13}, {9, 0.1}} *)
```

Some other ways

```
trimmedList ==
 Cases[list, _?(#[[1]] <= 9 &)] ==
 Cases[list, {_?(# <= 9 &), _}] ==
 DeleteCases[list, _?(#[[1]] > 9 &)] ==
 DeleteCases[list, {_?(# > 9 &), _}]

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 6):

I think:

`extractlist=DeleteCases[list, {x_, y_} /; x > 9]`

does the job.

Answer (score 6):

```
Select[list, #[[1]] <= 9 &]
```

Select is a reasonably simple method.

Answer (score 3):

If the xs are ordered in `list`

```
list[[;; Last[Ordering[Ordering[Append[list[[-1 ;; 1 ;; -1, 1]], 9.]]]] - 1]]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {4, 5}, {5, 9}, {8, 13}, {9, 0.1}}
> ```

Otherwise

```
Pick[list, Clip[list[[All, 1]], {9., 9.}, {9., 0}], 9.]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {4, 5}, {5, 9}, {8, 13}, {9, 0.1}}
> ```

Comment: The one involving Ordering is especially appealing.  +1

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{1, 2}, {4, 5}, {5, 9}, {8, 13}, {9, 0.1},
{15, -0.2}, {17, -9}, {23, 2}} /. {x_, _} /; x > 9 -> Sequence[]
```